Camera y Axle dont rotating
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3.0f;
    public float mouseSensitivity = 100.0f;
    public Transform playerBody;

    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    private float xRotation = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        Debug.Log("Mouse X: " + mouseX);
        Debug.Log("Mouse Y: " + mouseY);
        Debug.Log("Local Rotation Before: " + transform.localRotation);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        Debug.Log("Local Rotation After: " + transform.localRotation);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

        if (controller.isGrounded && velocity.y <= 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && controller.isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        Debug.Log("Mouse X: " + mouseX);
        Debug.Log("Mouse Y: " + mouseY);
        Debug.Log("Local Rotation: " + transform.localRotation);

    }
}

Video: https://youtu.be/c2iGfd8AqH0
When I rotate the camera on the Y axis, I see that it rotates and instantly returns to the zero point.
I tried to rewrite the camera movement but now it only rotates along the Y axis. What should I do?
I asked my friends but they themselves don’t know.

Look carefully at the tutorial again. The gameobject that PlayerMovement is attached to should be different from the gameobject playerBody is attached to. You have them both attached to the Capsule gameobject.  playerBody's gameobject should be a parent or other ancestor of PlayerMovement's gameobject.

I have a guess! Assuming the tutorial you're following works the way I think it does, the Y axis rotation is done by the player's body, and the X axis rotation is done on a child object that has the camera component.
My guess is that in the tutorial, the movement script is a component of the player body, and the mouse look script is a component of the camera! Your code has them both on the same object, so the rotation logic is messed up, and they're overwriting each other.
Instead, rotate them separately. CameraHolder should be the camera's Transform component. The camera should be a child of the playerBody.
    Debug.Log("Local Rotation Before: " + cameraHolder.localRotation);
    cameraHolder.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
    Debug.Log("Local Rotation After: " + cameraHolder.localRotation);
    playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);


Maybe I didn't understand what you meant, but I screwed up again.

I added the concept of "cameraHolder" :
'public Transform cameraHolder;'
Selected the camera as the “cameraHolder” object
Made the camera a child object
Observed something that doesn’t look like it’s working at all

link

Oh. i've made camera as floor child. All works thanks.
